# c# htmlagilitypack xpath select all except with certain class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to select all `li` tags on a page that do not have the `class="r"`

What i have so far is:

```
.//li
```

This is what ive tried so far

```
//li[not([@class='r'])]
```

With that i get the error:

> "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this expression `//li[not(@class='r')]`

```
var lis = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[not(@class='r')]")
```

Comment: +1 - i understood the [not] syntax but couldn;t for the life of me figure it for a not contains. for some reason, your answer consolidated it for me. here was my path: `//li[not(contains(@class,'noflag'))]` - thanks from windy SW scotland