# Get the value of a specific part of a div using agilityhtml

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the value of a div using agilitypack.my html code is like this :

```
<div class="div_5">
                <p>First Paragraph</p>
                <p>Second Paragraph</p>
                <p>Third Paragraph</p>
                <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>

<div class="div_6">
                <p>First Paragraph</p>
                <p>Second Paragraph</p>
                <p>Third Paragraph</p>
                <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
     </div>
                <p>other Paragraph</p>
                <p>other Paragraph</p>
  </div>
```

I need the content of `div_5` without the content of `div_6`,so i use this code :

```
    newsContent.Content = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_5']").InnerHtml;
```

But this code contains `div_5` and `div_6`.how can i remove `div_6` from my value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final code:

```
HtmlNode doc = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_5']");
                    HtmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_6']");
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: Ah, now you got RemoveChild() function. Glad to see it solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `innernode` first and then proceed.

```
var yourNode = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_5']")
var toBeRemoved = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//div[@class='_div_6']");

yourNode.RemoveChild(toBeRemoved,false);
//proceed with your code
newsContent.Content = yourNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: your RemoveChild doesn't exist in the function

Comment: It does exist in v1.4.0. What version of `HtmlAgilityPack` you're using? See the implementation for the `RemoveChild` function in the source code for 1.4.0 release http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs

Comment: <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.9" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649928/c-sharp-htmlagilitypack-xpath-select-all-except-with-certain-class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225438/htmlagilitypack-selectnodes-expression-to-ignore-an-element-with-a-certain-attri

Comment: @Ehsan Akbar I'll look over those questions tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used AgilityHTML, but try something along these lines:

```
var div5 = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_5']");

var div6 = div5.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='div_6']");

div6.Remove();

newsContent.Content = div5.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: DocumentNode can't be found in the var varriable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225438/htmlagilitypack-selectnodes-expression-to-ignore-an-element-with-a-certain-attri